# Unable to hot-deploy in JBoss

Tags: deployment, jboss, devops, hotdeploy

I want to hot-deploy application in JBoss and for that I found guide here [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Web_Platform/5/html/Getting_Started_Guide/The_JBoss_Server___A_Quick_Tour-Hot-deployment_of_services_in_JBoss.html)

I've downloaded JBoss-eap-7.0 but in that I don't see any folder with name jboss-as-web which is mentioned in the guide.

Can someone please help what is wrong here or other way to hot-deploy in JBoss?

For hot deploy, I have a war file of an application.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the documentation for **JBoss Enterprise Application Platform** not Web Platform (which is a litle bit different animal) at https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/